# Rearrange Projects under Work Experience on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I have a few Projects listed under my current place of work, as seen below:

[image]

Is there a way to rearrange these (preferably by date, start or completion)? Or would I have to remove them all and add them back in the correct sequence?

---

It would be superb if they can have this more like LinkedIn, where you can literally drag and drop these things into the sequence you please.

Comment: You like asking tough questions, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/edit-order-schools-facebook-profile-29755.html) is exceedingly dated:

> Facebook orders your education profile based on the order of entry. You can modify this by removing and re-entering your education profile one by one. This allows you to represent your education profile in your preferred order

but other than FB automatically sorting the most recent first (as I thought I had seen somewhere but can't now find) it may be your best bet.